# 415 Unsupported Media Type in PostMan but not in curl

Tags: rest, curl, postman, restful-url

I call this Rest method through curl and its working fine:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{ "email": "nunuet@gmail.com" }' "http://129.162.231.137:1133/calzada/api/v1/users/pwd"
```

But when I call the same method using PostMan I got a 415 error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see two main problems:

1. In body request you are sending an invalid Json, because you add -d before and simple quote at the end (eliminate both).
2. You don't set header/content type right. To achieve it click in Text (on the right binary button) and set in JSON (aplication/json), with that postman add header for request.

Example:

[image: Postman Example]

*PD: I tried make your request, but I never receive an 200 status code, most requests were timeout (I don't know if you run that server locally or have a special proxy configuration).*

Answer (score 0):

I navigated to `Postman` at `Headers` tab while making making requests and enabled Content-Type. I ticked it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKL9e.png)

Comment: So, content-type needs to be set? The accepted answer already states that.